# EventDispatcher and Function Issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am very new to AS3 and I am trying to make a simple flash game prototype. Right now, all I am trying to do is get flash to tell me it is actually receiving the key input of the user, but I have run into the following 2 issues:

1. On my lines where I am adding event listeners to the Stage, I am getting an Error1061: Call to Possibly Undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.

   - My research has led me to believe that this is because my Backlayer class does not    extend EventDispatcher, but I cannot extend that because Backlayer must extend MovieClip
2. On those same lines, I am trying to tell the code that when such an event occurs, to perform the named function, but I get an error1120 telling me that both are undefined properties.

   - I think this may because the class is not extending event dispatcher yet?

My understanding of AS3 is all self-taught and I am still trying to learn the etiquette of the language, so I apologize if this is a really simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer just from googling that works yet. 
Here is my code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
public class Backlayer extends MovieClip
{
Stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownHandler);
Stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpHandler);

public function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
{
    trace("left pressed");
}

else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
{
    trace("right pressed");
}

else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
{
    trace("up pressed");
}

else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
{
    trace("down pressed");
}

}
public function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
{
    trace("left released");
}

else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
{
    trace("right released");
}

else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
{
    trace("up released");
}

else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
{
    trace("down released");
}

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MovieClip does inherit from EventDispatcher, thus your class should as well.
See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html

Following rows have two problems:

```
Stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownHandler);
Stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpHandler);
```

1) They are not in body of a function.

2) Stage.addEventListener means that you're trying to call static function of Stage class. It should be written stage.addEventListener (calling function of instance of Stage class stored in property stage).

Comment: Thank you, that moved me along.